# Как запустить питоновский скрипт в консоли?

Tags: python, консоль, linux

Есть скрипт `scriptname.py` который находится по пути `/home/foldername/`Нужно запустить скрипт в консоли без указания пути (`cd` не предлагать). Просто указывать путь каждый раз лень.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. chmod +x    /home/foldername/scriptname.py
2. cp /home/foldername/scriptname.py /usr/bin/
3. scriptname.py

Comment: Нужен другой способ. В папке foldername есть зависимости (без них никуда). Моя вина, неточно описал.

Comment: Какие еще зависимости, опишите тогда подробнее.

Comment: Вообще это google app engine и мне нужно делать так: appcfg.py update .То есть в папке куча скриптов и все они нужны.

Comment: На любой случай жизни...alias GO='appcfg.py update /home/foldername/'

Comment: Cпасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

в ~/.bashrc прописать export PATH="$PATH:/home/foldername/"при этом плодить копии файлов как предложил pyatak не надо